# Refreshing/using active geometry bounds using Google Earth Engine app-side for data export

Tags: google-earth-engine, dem, geometry, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

This is my first time posting here, so bear with me. This is a continuation of the response to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344680/exporting-image-from-app-side-using-google-earth-engine), but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I am working on this [GEE Web App](https://valfred.users.earthengine.app/view/elevationimageryexplorerv2) where the user can download hillshaded elevation data with the click of a download button. I have it set up so that when you click the button, a .tiff file that is clipped to a geometry will download (using getDownloadURL). At the current moment, it's clipped to the screen-extent geometry (using Map.getBounds), but it would be more useful if it could be clipped to a user-drawn polygon geometry (on the app-side).

My problem is that the geometry (screen-extent) is only defined when the script is run. This isn't a huge deal in the code editor because I can re-run the script when I am satisfied with my screen extent. However, on the App side of things, there is no "Run" button and refreshing the page gets me back to square one. How can the geometry, which feeds the region field of the downloadImg function, be updated as the App user explores the Web App?

Can this be done with a user-drawn polygon (I've tried using 'geometry' in the region field and using the geometry tools, but once again, the Web App does not re-define geometry after it has loaded so the download button does not work.
Here's my script:

```
//GEOMETRY SETTINGS
// Define export geometry to screen extent ('viewBounds')
var viewBounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(Map.getBounds());

//DATASET IMPORTS
//USGS 3DEP 1m National Map
var _3DEP1mFull = ee.ImageCollection('USGS/3DEP/1m'); //FullExtent
_3DEP1mFull = _3DEP1mFull.map(function(image) {
  var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade(image);
  return image.addBands(hillshade);
});
var _3DEP1mBounded = _3DEP1mFull //ViewBounded
  .filterBounds(viewBounds);
print(_3DEP1mBounded, '3DEP collection')



//IMAGE COLLECTION TO IMAGE
//USGS 3DEP 1m National Map
var _3DEP1mImg = _3DEP1mBounded
  .select('hillshade') //select hillshade band
  .mosaic(); //mosaic images within ViewBounds
print(_3DEP1mImg, '_3DEP1mImg')



//ADDING LAYERS TO THE MAP
//USGS 3DEP 1m National Map
Map.addLayer(_3DEP1mImg, {}, 'USGS 3DEP 1m Hillshade ViewBounded', false); //ViewBounded
Map.addLayer(_3DEP1mFull.select('hillshade'), {}, 'USGS 3DEP 1m Hillshade FullExtent', false); //FullExtent




// Define a function to generate a download URL of the image for the
// viewport region. 
function downloadImg() {
  var downloadArgs = {
    name: 'ee_image',
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    scale: 1,
    region: viewBounds.toGeoJSONString() //alternatively, geometry.toGeoJSONString() for hand drawn geometries.
 };
 var url = _3DEP1mImg.getDownloadURL(downloadArgs);
 urlLabel.setUrl(url);
 urlLabel.style().set({shown: true});
}

// Add UI elements to the Map.
var downloadButton = ui.Button('Download 3DEP 1m', downloadImg);
var urlLabel = ui.Label('Download', {shown: false});
var panel = ui.Panel([downloadButton, urlLabel]);
Map.add(panel);
```

Ignore the NAIP datasets in the Web App.

I am aware of the size limitations of `getDownloadURL`, this app is being used to extract not very spatially extensive elevation data. I am not concerned about preserving metadata in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are defining the `viewBounds` upon the initialization of your app, and you never update it.

Consider the following minimal example:

```js
// Here you get viewBounds when the app starts 
// So the user hasn't had the chance to move the map yet. 
var viewBounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(Map.getBounds());
print(viewBounds) 

function printMapBounds(){
  // This will be done every time the user clicks the button. 
  var viewBounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(Map.getBounds());
  print(viewBounds)
  // Now you can do something useful with viewBounds here 
  // such as preparing and downloading the image you want. 
}

var downloadButton = ui.Button('Download 3DEP 1m', printMapBounds)
var panel = ui.Panel([downloadButton]);
Map.add(panel);
```

The first call to Map.getBounds is what you currently have, and it gets the Map bounds upon initialization of the app, which is not very useful. Instead, consider the call to `Map.getBounds` defined *inside* the function that you are building, in this case I simply called it `printMapBounds`. In this small example, this function is called when the ui.Button called "downloadButton" is clicked. To make this clearer, we could rewrite it as:

```js
var downloadButton = ui.Button('Download 3DEP 1m');
downloadButton.onClick(printMapBounds);
```

that is, you can assign the `onClick` method for downloadButton after you define the button itself. This will be useful as your app grows.

In general, I recommend following the "Publishing and Earth Engine App to Accompany your Research Paper" tutorial. You can find the resources for this tutorial here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uq3llHg8sQJkQICw6swugv_qCW8DqmbLTpltsPj7EIw/edit#heading=h.yvrr2oxxm0zk

Comment: Hi Oliver, thank you for your response. I redefined the map boundaries within the function, and this allows me to move around the map and export different regions without having to re-run the script, however, only on the dev side. On the client side, I am still not able to generate an export link. Here is my snapshot [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c19f205ebec833c7c132a4aee21bd8fc?noload=true) and here is the app its running [link](https://valfred.users.earthengine.app/view/elevationimageryexplorerv21). I've been racking my head around this, and can't quite figure out what's wrong.